# Queueable job not timeout with retryUntil()

Tags: laravel, queue

I've tried to used `retryUntil()` method on queueable long running job, as below:

```
public function handle()
{
    // time for execution 16-18 sec
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 1000000000; $x++) {
        $b = 1 + 1;
    } 
}

public function retryUntil()
{
    return now()->addSeconds(5);
}
```

Queue worker command (without any options):

`php artisan queue:work`

But after 5 seconds, job still running, not timeout.

Please help me understand how to `retryUntil()` work? Any example with this method?

Thank you.

Laravel Version: 5.6.17.
PHP Version: 7.2.4 (pcntl enable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding options to queue worker:
`php artisan queue:work --timeout=5`

FYI: check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts

Comment: After reread docs, I've got it clear now. Thank for your help.